# Need Basic Information about Using Reference to an Instance Method of a Particular Object

Tags: java, object, reference

I'm a moderately experienced C++ guy learning Java.  I'm struggling to understand references that "point" to a specific instance of an object.  In C++, this would be easy.  But the more I Google "*java reference to an instance object,*" the more I read and the more confused I get about how this sort of thing works in Java.

Let me illustrate a specific example.  Suppose I wanted to create a boxing simulation.  Below is (abbreviated) code which sets up the boxers and lets them duke it out.  At the end of the fight, I'd like a "WinnerReference" reference to "point" to the last boxer standing:

```
public class Boxer {

  String Name;

  public Boxer(String a) {
    Name = a;
  }

  String GetName()  { return Name; }
}

public class BoxingRing {

  public BoxingRing() {
    // Do nothing
  }
  void FightFightFight(Boxer a, Boxer b, >>WinnerReference<< )
    // Boxers fight here
    // WinnerReference is pointed to winning boxer here
  }
}

public class BoxingMatch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      Boxer Joe = new Boxer("Joe");
      Boxer Sam = new Boxer("Sam");
      BoxingRing TheRing = new BoxingRing();
      // Create reference called "WinnerReference" of type Boxer here

      TheRing.FightFightFight(Sam, Joe, WinnerReference);
      System.out.println("The winner of this boxing match was:  " + WinnerReference::GetName());
      }
}
```

I've been researching this all afternoon, but can't find a tutorial which directly leads me through what I'm trying to do.  (You can probably see that I'm approaching this from a C++ perspective.)

What I'd like to ask the forum is this:  Is this a feasible approach for for a Java program?  Am I Googling for the correct terminology?  Is there a good resource someone could recommend?

Many thanks!
              -P

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/141834/how-is-a-java-reference-different-from-a-c-pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to WinningReference, you are passing the value of it (which is null at that point), not a pointer to it.  What would be a more common approach in Java would be:

```
Boxer fightFightFight(Boxer a, Boxer b)
    // Boxers fight here    
    return winner;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> At the end of the fight, I'd like a "WinnerReference" reference to "point" to the last boxer standing

It sounds like you're looking for pass-by-reference. That doesn't exist in Java - all values are passed by value, but for any non-primitive types the value of the expression is a reference anyway. That's *not* the same as pass-by-reference though.

Generally, the best way to get round this limitation - is to simply use a return value instead:

```
Boxer fightFightFight(Boxer a, Boxer b) {
    // Boxers fight here
    return winner; // Or whatever
}
```

Then in your calling code:

```
Boxer winner = ring.fightFightFight(sam, joe);
```

It's important to understand that you won't be creating any *new* `Boxer` objects here (unless you do so explicitly, of course) - you'll just be returning a reference to one of the existing ones.

In C++, this would be somewhat equivalent to

```
Boxer* fightFightFight(Boxer *a, Boxer *b)
```

... if that helps!

(It would be a good idea to start following Java naming conventions right now, by the way.)

Answer (score 3):

That isn't possible in Java because it is pass by value. You can pass a `Boxer` instance in (by value) because the value **is** *the reference*.  Java naming convention is camel case (lower letter first) for methods. Either return a `Boxer`, or pass in another reference like

```
void fightFightFight(Boxer a, Boxer b, Boxer theChamp) {
  // if a wins...
    theChampe.setName(a.getName());
  // .. or if b wins
    theChampe.setName(b.getName());
}
```

Or return the winner

```
Boxer fightFightFight(Boxer a, Boxer b) {
  // if a wins...
    return a;
  // otherwise
    return b;
}
```

Finally, Java is not C++.